# JLabel Icon not showing after change

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I tried looking up this question, but most of the answers are that the file path is wrong, but that's most likely not the case. The file works the 1st time I use it.

I am making a battleships game, and use JLabels to show ships on map. I want to make a button to rotate ship from horizontal to vertical but it's icon disappears when I try to change it.

When I run this constructor code:

```
public Ship(int size, String direction, boolean active, Client c,
        ClientGUI cg) {
    this.c = c;
    this.cg = cg;
    health = size;
    this.active = active;
    this.direction = direction;

    file = "img/" + Integer.toString(health) + direction + ".png";   // String
    try {
        System.out.println(file);
        tx = ImageIO.read(new File(file));    // BufferedImage
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    texture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tx));
    if (direction.equals("v"))
        texture.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40 * size);
    else
        texture.setBounds(0, 0, 40 * size, 40);
    texture.setVisible(true);

}
```

everything works and I can see the image.

But then I try to rotate it, using pretty much the same code:

```
void rotate() {
    if (direction.equals("h")) {
        direction = "v";
        file = "img/" + Integer.toString(health) + direction + ".png";
        try {
            System.out.println(file);
            tx = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        texture.setBounds(0,0,40, 40 * size);
        texture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tx));

    } else {
        direction = "h";
        file = "img/" + Integer.toString(health) + direction + ".png";
        try {
            System.out.println(file);
            tx = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        texture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tx));
        texture.setBounds(0,0,40 * size, 40);
    }

    cg.repaint();    // not sure if I need to do this
}
```

and it disappears...

I tried placing two ships, one is rotated, it's just missing the JLabel or the icon on JLabel.[image]

Comment: Google "How do I compare Strings in Java". Im too lazy to link it

Comment: Very bad string comparison in this way `direction == "h"` that is wrong.

Comment: @Braj ok i fixed it but that's not really related to my question

Comment: how would I know that it's not causing the issue? It's good step in the direction of solving this issue.

Comment: Where are the files been stored? Are they in the src or are they external files

Comment: @MadProgrammer they are in seprate folder `img` in project directory. http://scr.hu/15in/oig8m

Comment: The next step would be to use something like `System.out.println(new File(file).exists());` to verify that the image is accessible...

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer `File.exists()` returns `true` every time

Comment: @AndrewThompson I changed it to `tx = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(file));` but it only load the 1st time again, and then it throws an exception `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`. The Ship object rotates but the texture doesn't http://scr.hu/15in/gu91e .

Comment: Okay, so the next possibly issue is the fact that texture hasn't actually been added to the container to begin with. Start by setting the name of your main container (where you think texture should reside) and the use getParent on texture to see if 1- it's null and 2- the name of the parent matches your expectations

Comment: @MadProgrammer the container returns `null`. Do I need to add the image again every time I change it? Also, is a JLabel a valid container? Because my grid is a JLabel and I've been adding the ship textures to it. Should i change it to the panel holding the grid? Or maybe add a JPanel over the grid to hold the ships?

Comment: No, JLabel is a valid continuer, I assume you're using to display a background image. Texture should be added to a container at least once, beyond that, you should be able to switch the icon of the label and it should update. I'd make sure that what you think you're updating is actually what you're updating, chekc the references of your textures to ensure that you're not create new instances when you don't need them

Comment: @MadProgrammer what does `getParent()` do excactly ? Because I tried this code: `cg.lblGrid2.add(texture);
  System.out.println(texture.getParent().getName());` and it returns null, even though i just added it to a JLabel `lblGrid2`.

Comment: GetName is returning null, not getParent ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you update the `JLabel texture` by calling a method which changes it's state, it may or may not be updated immediately unless you call `texture.repaint()` or `texture.paintAll(texture.getGraphics())`, or some similar method.

Also, I would look into using a `LayoutManager` for whatever upper level component you are using to hold your grid of JLabels.  If you use a `GridLayout` of your game board and either:

1. set the JLabel's preferred size with `texture.setPreferredSize(Dimension)` and call `frame.pack()` once when setting up your game; or
2. set the JLabel's size with `label.setSize(Dimension)` once and don't pack your JFrame

You will only need to set the size of the JLabel once, not every time you set a new ImageIcon to the label.  Because, Ideally your game shouldn't be doing any extra work that it doesn't have to so it performs faster.

I would also recommend maintaining every possible ImageIcon as static fields in your class, rather than accessing them from the file every time.  That way, you read them once from a static initializing method, which then reach ship can directly access when changing the direction.

Comment: Isn't number 2 the same as I already have done? I do have `repaint()` also called to my whole window. I use absolute layout. I set the JLabel's size every time because  the image size also changes.

Comment: `If you update the JLabel texture by calling a method which changes it's state, it may or may not be updated immediately unless you call` - Whenever you change a property of a Swing component it will invoke revalidate() and repaint() on itself, you do NOT need to invoke repaint manually.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a button to rotate ship from horizontal to vertical

You can use the [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) class to do the rotation for you.

Comment: Can't this be done the way I did it? I dont actually need to rotate the image, as I have separate files for horizontal and vertical and I just want to swap them.